# If string can be composed of certain characters?

Tags: python

I'd like to determine if a string can be created using only characters in a list. For example,

```
>>>acceptableChars = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
>>>print isAcceptable("abc")
True
>>>print isAcceptable("xyz")
False
```

Comment: What is there to try? Google gave nothing.

Comment: "What is there to try?" Code you wrote!

Comment: It's extremely rare that Google actually gives "nothing" as a result. What did you search for?

Comment: @GregHewgill "python if string is made of characters", "python if string can be composed of characters", etc.

Comment: The first result from the first search is an SO question, whose second answer does exactly what you want. (It's probably not the first solution I'd consider, or even the 10th, but that's a different issue…)

Comment: @abarnert: a link to that post might help the OP instead of just saying such a link exists

Comment: @tkbx: What is the correct output of `isAcceptable` when `acceptableChars = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']` and you want to check for `'aabccd'`?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I'm using this to check if something is a hash (0-9, a-f), so any number of duplicates would be acceptable.

Comment: @tkbx: Why didn't you ask that in the first place? That's much easier!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a set from `acceptableChars`:

```
>>> acceptableChars = set('abcdefghi')
```

Now we can make isAcceptable check if any of the characters in its argument are not in `acceptableChars` using set subtraction:

```
>>> def isAcceptable(s):
    return set(s) <= acceptableChars
>>> isAcceptable("abc")
True
>>> isAcceptable("xyz")
False
```

Comment: Why take the `len` of the set and compare it to 0, instead of just using the boolean value of the set itself?

Comment: Better yet, I'll use the `<=` to check if `acceptableChars` is a superset of `set(s)`.

Comment: Yep, that's the solution I was hoping the OP would come up with if he knew a bit about set theory. :)

Answer (score 3):

Since your actual use case is:

> I'm using this to check if something is a hash (0-9, a-f), so any number of duplicates would be acceptable

How about this:

```
intvalue = int(possiblehash, 16)
```

If this succeeds, that means it was a valid hex string—and you have the value, in case you need it. If it raises an exception, it wasn't a valid hex string. So:

```
try:
   intvalue = int(possiblehash, 16)
except Exception as e:
   print("That's not a hex string! Python says " + str(e))
```

If you want to use a different means to convert the hex string into some appropriate form instead of an integer, the exact same idea will apply:

```
try:
    binvalue = binascii.unhexlify(possiblehash)
except Exception as e:
   print("That's not a hex string! Python says " + str(e))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def isAcceptable(text, acceptableChars=set("abcdefghi")):
    return all(char in acceptableChars for char in text)
```

Comment: This is guaranteed to work only if `text` contains no duplicate characters

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: No, it's iterating over each character in `text`; if you have duplicate characters, it will check each duplicate, and get the same result as for the previous duplicate. So it's guaranteed to work every time.

Comment: Yours will give a false positive when `text='aaa'` and `chars='abc'`

Comment: How is `aaa` a false positive? Each `a` is in `abc`.

Comment: Because there's only one 'a'. How are you able to use 3 'a's when you only have one 'a' in `chars`?

Comment: OK, now I can see how @inspectorG4dget interpreted the question: can `text` be made up only out of a permutation of `acceptableChars`. I don't think it's what the OP intended, but the question is a little vague, and it's definitely not a totally unreasonable interpretation.

Comment: @kindall: OP's question was unclear. Your solution is clearly correct (with OP's notes). Apparently now, I can't undo my downvote as it was made >30 minutes ago. If you make a small edit to your post, I can undo my downvote

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to just loop over the string:

```
def isAcceptable(s):
    for c in s:
        if not isAcceptableChar(c):
            return False
    return True
```

It should be pretty obvious how to write the `isAcceptableChar` function.

Of course if you know a bit more about Python, you'd probably just write:

```
def isAcceptable(s):
    return all(isAcceptableChar(c) for c in s)
```

And if you know a bit about set theory, you can probably come up with a more efficient and simpler implementation.

But first get the basic one working, and then think about how to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [52]: all(c in acceptableChars and acceptableChars.count(c)==want.count(c) for c in want)
Out[52]: True

In [53]: acceptableChars = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']

In [54]: want = 'abc'

In [55]: all(c in acceptableChars and acceptableChars.count(c)==want.count(c) for c in want)
Out[55]: True

In [56]: want = 'xyz'

In [57]: all(c in acceptableChars and acceptableChars.count(c)==want.count(c) for c in want)
Out[57]: False
```

Though, the following is a much better way to do this:

```
def isAcceptable(text, chars):
    store = collections.Counter(chars)
    for char in text:
        if char not in store or not store[char]:
            return False
        store[char] -= 1
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way i can think of:  check whether `yourString.strip('all your acceptable chars')` returns you a blank string.

```
def isAcceptable(text, acceptable='abcdefghi'):
    return text.strip(acceptable) == ''
```

If the `strip` returns `''`, then the only chars in `text` were in `acceptable` as well.