# String composed of only acceptable characters

Tags: python

What would be the **best** way to check if string is composed only of acceptable characters?

What you think about this:

```
acceptableChars = ['a', 'b', ...]

all(char in acceptableChars for char in string)
```

Comment: `return string == "acceptable"` ;-)

Comment: Do you mean ASCII characters?

Comment: I assume you're reposting [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19759096/validating-data-in-wxpython). If you don't feel like it's got enough attention or that you've explained yourself well enough please edit it to include more information rather than reposting.

Comment: Make `acceptableChars` a set (instead of a list) for a major speed boost.

Comment: @Ben Question you are refering to consists of two rather different parts - the first one is generall so indeed, I did a repost. The second one is specific to wxPython though, so I left it there.

Comment: [If string can be composed of certain characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13849295/1667218)

Comment: It is strange to use the same variable names isn't it? Yet it **is** coincidence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert both to sets and check that `set(string)` is a subset of `acceptableChars`

```
return set(string).issubset(set(acceptableChars))
```

In action:

```
>>> acceptableChars = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> string1 = 'bacca'
>>> string2 = 'barca'
>>> set(string1)
set(['a', 'c', 'b'])
>>> set(string2)
set(['a', 'r', 'b', 'c'])
>>> set(string1).issubset(set(acceptableChars))
True
>>> set(string2).issubset(set(acceptableChars))
False
>>>
```

(Ignore earlier version, was not paying full attention.)

Comment: There is no more efficient way I suppose then?

Comment: @Mios, it depends.  If a majority of input strings are wholly acceptable, then you have to check every character, and set operations are fastest.  But if you have many unacceptable strings, looping can be unboundedly faster because you have the chance to "get out early" then.

Answer (score -1):

```
sorted(set(acceptable_chars_string)) == sorted(set(input_string))
```

Comment: Is it _really_ efficient? And i think that it won't work if I have multiple occurences of the same character in `input_string`?

Comment: * Python, I hate it. Because of all of this.<br /> Ruby `@input_string.strip.uniq.sort == @acceptable_chars_string.sort.uniq`

Comment: This won't work if `input_string` uses only some but not all of the acceptable characters.